# Why does INSERT trigger only send one email?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, email, triggers

I have a table with the following structure

```
id | full_name | email
-------------------------------
1  | Ahmad     | ahmad@some.com
2  | Jack      | jack@another.com
3  | Mike      | mike@yetanother.com
. .    ..          ..
```

and so on.

and I have created the following trigger to send an email to the person who's email was just inserted (as a welcome message):

```
create TRIGGER welcome_user ON users
AFTER INSERT
AS
begin
  declare @email varchar(100)
  declare @full_name varchar(200)
  declare @html varchar(4000)

  select @email=i.email,@full_name=i.full_name from inserted i


  set @html = 'Dear ' + @full_name + '<br><br> Welcome...'  

begin
  exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  @profile_name =  'SQL Database Mail'
     ,  @recipients =   @email
     ,  @copy_recipients = 'admin@mycompany.com' 
     ,  @from_address = 'admin@mycompany.com'
     ,  @subject =  'Welcome'
     ,  @body_format = 'HTML'
     ,  @body = @html

end

end
GO
```

Now the above code will work if one row is inserted:

```
insert into users (id,full_name,email) values (900,'Jason','jason@email.com')
```

The user will receive an email, and I will be copied (because I have access to `admin@mycompany.com` )

But the problem occurs when a bunch of rows are inserted all at once, doing something like this:

```
insert into users (id,full_name,email) 
   select id,full_name,email from temp_users where validated='Y'
```

In the above example, only one email as sent (the first row that gets inserted). The other ones are inserted to the table, but no email is sent to them. Neither a copy is sent to me.

What could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers fire once per statement - not once per row. Therefore, the `inserted` table has more than one row in your trigger - you are only using one. What you should do is copy the records from the inserted table into a table variable and loop though it.

As @Aaron Bertrand has pointed out - a better solution would be to remove the mail dependency from within your trigger to a stored procedure - an have that processed asynchronously. With this solution, your trigger would populate a table that acts as a queue. You would then have a procedure that reads this queue and sends emails. This procedure could be scheduled (using a SQL Agent or a Service Broker) or even run manually. For more info see [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2231/avoid-external-dependencies-in-sql-server-triggers/) and [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers).

Comment: Not sure why you need to copy the rows to a table variable. Also you can potentially build the database mail commands with set-based concatenation without needing any of the explicit looping. Or better yet, [push the rows to a queue table and let some background process pick up the mails to send](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers.aspx).

Comment: `SELECT @sql += N'EXEC dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = N''' + i.email + ''',...' FROM inserted AS i;`

Comment: I'm not saying that's necessarily a good idea (since someone could have put literally *anything* into that e-mail column), I'm just saying you can do that without looping.

Comment: I find concatenation much easier to write, read and maintain than messy looping or cursor scaffolding. I also like chocolate and hate cream cheese. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand after some further research, I think the better solution is to remove the external mail dependency from within the trigger - as you have suggested in your first comment. I have added it to the answer.